# How can i analyse this motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, earth, sun

[image]

Hello
(Im from south Korea. im sorry for my english in physics.)

im curious about this gravitational spiral motion.
can its trajectory and time took to collide be guessable? or can i calculate this movement?
picture depicts sun centered on it and earth falling into sun.
(because some meteor crash)
I want to analyse trajectory of earth in this spiral motion
and time took for the earth to be crashed into sun, with given velocity and etc..
how can i analyse this? please give me some hints,,

if you need more info about my question then please leave comment on it.

Comment: A simple, single impulse (meteor impact) would nudge the orbit a little and make it elliptical (assuming it was circular of course). It won't result in a spiral. But a constant force, pointing inward toward the Sun would result in a spiral and eventually a fiery end, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of trajectory that you have drawn is unphysical.

I recommend that you look up depictions of the orbit of Halley's comet.

When Halley's comet has reached it's furthest distance to the Sun the comet is moving quite slowly. The subsequent motion back to the center of the solar system is almost straight towards the Sun. Except, it's not quite straight towards the Sun.

Because of the gravity of the Sun the comet gains velocity all the way to the center of the solar system. By the time the comet is close to the Sun the velocity is so large that the gravity of the Sun is not enough to pull the comet all the way in.

Instead the comet swings *around* the Sun, and then the velocity of the comet *carries it away* from the Sun again, all the way to the same distance away from the Sun.

In the case of the Earth:
If something would change the orbit of the Earth, away from circular orbit, then the orbit changes from circular to ellipse-shaped.

An inward spiral, in the way you represent, cannot happen. In the process of being attracted by the Sun the comet or planet or what have you gains velocity. It gains so much velocity that it will swing *around* the Sun.

Comment: Im sorry what? Are you claiming that something can't spiral in a gravitational field?

Comment: Halley explained by Astronomy Now: https://astronomynow.com/2016/07/01/chaotic-orbit-of-comet-halley-explained/ I think your term *'swing around the Sun'* is a bit misleading.

Comment: Take a satellite in a stable, circular orbit. Now apply a constant  force to it, its vector always pointing away from the Earth (or large central mass). Surely such a satellite will spiral towards the 'centre'?

Comment: @SeñorO I'm baffled by this answer too...

Comment: Ooopsie: *its vector always pointing away from the Earth* should read *its vector always pointing to the centre of the Earth* My bad.

Comment: Well, the question sounds like the only modification to Earth's orbit is a single impact. That would at best lead to a more elliptical orbit, which I think is what this answer is trying to convey.

Comment: @KristofferSjöö What is confusing about this answer is the reference to Halley. The last two paragraphs of the answer appear correct to me. The OP isn't considering a constant, centripetal force which  could make the mass spiral towards its central mass.

Comment: The equations of motion for Newtonian gravitation give you conic sections for orbits.  Spiraling into the central force is not one of the choices unless some continuous external force is acting.  You can get spiral orbits from general relativistic gravitation, however.

Comment: thank you for the guys.

Comment: and i have more questions,, If i clean the universe except sun and just put some mass on somewhere(without revolving or rotationing), then it would interact with the Sun and fall into it, isnt it?

Comment: oh im confused,, in what condition does the mass orbits in elliptic orbit or fall into the sun by making spiral trajectory?

Comment: i thought it was based on whether the mass's velocity is below or over v=sqrt(GM/r) but i found it doesnt determine the shape of its orbit ,,